# VS Code Terminal Won't Map Option Key to Meta

Tags: terminal, keyboard, visual-studio-code, iterm2

I am trying to enable the option/alt key as Meta in my terminal in VS Code. I set the `"terminal.integrated.macOptionIsMeta": true` in my `settings.json` but it is not working.

I made this same change to my system Terminal app and iTerm2.

iTerm is the only one that works. In iTerm the option key is mapped to Meta but not in the VS Code terminal or Terminal.

Does anyone know why this could be or how to correct it?

```
OS X 10.15.7
VS Code Version: 1.63.2
iTerm2 Build 3.4.12
Terminal Version 2.10 (433)
```

VS Code

[image]

[image]

iTerm2
[image]

Terminal

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an issue with how OS X handles tmux-keyboard integration, not VS Code.

The relationship between Option/Alt and Esc/Meta does not work well. Even if this feature is enabled in your terminal emulator. Consequently, when binding the Meta+ to an action in `.tmux.conf` the resulting behavior is not as expected.

```
bind -n M-j select-pane -L
bind -n M-k ​select-pane -R
```

`Alt+j` and `Alt+k` work as expected.

However, when binding the Meta+[DirectionKey]:

```
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
```

`Alt+Left` and `Alt+Right` do NOT work and you need to use `Esc+Left` and `Esc+Right`.

Answer (score 1):

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPsae.png)

In iTerm2, I changed the meta-key behavior by hitting `COMMAND`+`,`, and updating `Keys`>`Remap Modifiers`.

This allows for normal terminal navigation (such as `OPT`+`b` to go back one word) instead of printing bizarre characters.

In VSCode, `COMMAND`+`,` will also open preferences, where you can search for "meta" and find some settings related to similar behaviors.

I have not found a way to modify the actual code editor, but I note that I can enable the same behaviors (`OPT`+`d` to delete a word, for example) in the build in terminal. VSCode's terminal may be opened with `SHIFT`+`CTRL`+`~`.